# How to sum scheduled work hours for a user?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I wonder if it's possible to sum up a user's scheduled work hours?

I have customized the user entity and added a field that I want to show the user's total defined work hours in for the current week. But I don't know how to access the entity containing work hours. The problem is that I'm in an online organization and I can't access the database.

I've tried downloading SDK and of course googling. Since I'm a beginner I haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an example for **selecting time spans** of working hours of a certain user. It's found in the SDK but, given that the example is written as a console application in C#, it might be perceived as complicated an unnecessarily complicated.

Also, it's mentioned that there's a field on the user entity, I assume that for this particular task, JavaScript might be more suitable and such an example I haven't seen.

This page presenting the source code is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The bottom line is that you create a service and then execute the below.

```csharp
QueryScheduleRequest scheduleRequest = new QueryScheduleRequest
{
  ResourceId = GetRegardedUserId(),
  Start = DateTime.Now,
  End = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14),
  TimeCodes = new TimeCode[] { TimeCode.Available }
};
QueryScheduleResponse scheduleResponse 
  = (QueryScheduleResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(scheduleRequest);
```

For more information on how to handle the requests to scheduling and working hours see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334234.aspx) article and for service appointments look [over here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328326.aspx).